# What are the differences between Cognos and SPSS modeler products?

Tags: business-intelligence, feature-comparison, cognos

My school wants to start doing some data mining, and probably go with an IBM product. I've done a fair amount of searching, but the differences between the two products seem cloudy to those of us who haven't had experience with data mining. Can anyone offer some help, or direction, as to what the differences in these products are? Although the main goal is helping with retention and graduation rates, BI features in general are also of interest to the school.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between Cognos and Modeler are very large.  Cognos is mainly a summary and reporting tool.  It does not do any statistical analysis to speak of (except when you use the part of SPSS Statistics that is optionally integrated into one of the Studios).  Modeler is a full data mining tool with many modeling capabilities.  Modeler can read and write Cognos data.